# Fail to access my Model fields in the views using /<int:pk>/ in the urls

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-urls

I have a model called **Primary** and I want to access the fields of the models inside my viewStudent template, because I have more fields in the models.

the model:

```
class Primary(models.Model):
    profilePicture = models.ImageField(blank=False, null=False)
    firstName = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=False, null=False) 
    sureName = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=False, null=False) 
    lastName = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=False, null=False)  
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=False)
    classOf = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False, null=False)
    yearOfGraduations = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False, null=False)
    hobbies = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False)
    dateOfBirth = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    year = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

when I type this inside my: viewAlbum template it's throws me an error like this: **NoReverseMatch at /viewAlbum Reverse for 'view-Student' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['view/(?P[0-9]+)/\Z']**

```
<a href="{% url 'view-Student' primaries.id %}">view Students</a>
```

the urls.py

```
path('viewAlbum', views.viewAlbum, name='view-Album'),
path('view/<int:pk>/', views.viewStudent, name='view-Student'),
```

the views:

```
def viewAlbum(request):
    primaries = Primary.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'viewAlbum.html', {'primaries': primaries})

def viewStudent(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Primary, id=pk)

    primaries = Primary.objects.get(id=pk)
    return render(request, 'viewStudent.html', {'post': post, 'primaries': primaries})
```

inside my viewAlbum template I have tried this:

```
<a href="{% url 'view-Student' primaries.pk %}">view Students</a>
```

the viewAlbum template:

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        {% for prima in primaries %}
        <div class="col">
            <div class="card my-2" style="width: 18rem;">
                <img src="{{ prima.profilePicture.url }}" alt="" class="card-img-top">

                <div class="card-body">
                    <p>{{ prima.firstName }}</p>
                    <br>
                    <a href="{% url 'view-Student' prima.pk %}">view Students</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

the viewStudents template:

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="row justify-content-center">
                    <img src="{{ prima.profilePicture.url }}" alt="" class="card-img-top">
                    <p>{{ prima.firstName }}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

but it's not working

How can I solves this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view,

```py
def viewAlbum(request):
    primaries = Primary.objects.all()  # RETURNS ALL 

    return render(request, 'viewAlbum.html', {'primaries': primaries})
```

primaries does not have a pk, since it is a queryset.

Perhaps you mean to iterate through ALL the Primary objects, something like this?

```html
{% for p in primaries %}
    <a href="{% url 'view-Student' p.pk %}">view Student</a>

{% endfor %}
```

**Edit**
The name you pass through the view must match the one you use in the template.  Since you are using the name `prima` in your template, then that is what you must pass in the view:

```py
def viewStudent(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Primary, id=pk)

    prima = Primary.objects.get(id=pk)
    return render(request, 'viewStudent.html', {'post': post, 'prima': prima})
```

Comment: So what should I do now ?? The code I wrote in the question is the one you wrote in the answer

Comment: @AdamuAbdulkarim, what I changed is the template, not the view.

Comment: It's takes me to the template I want, but the field isn't display the content of my Primary model.

Comment: @AdamuAbdulkarim, edit your question with your full html templates, both the viewAlbum.html and the viewStudent.html templates, and I'll show you how to change them.  The error is not in your views, but in the templates.

Comment: I update the question sir

Comment: @AdamuAbdulkarim, the `<a>` tags have something very different than in your original question.  But I've edited my answer.  The name passed in the context of your view must match the `{{ prima }}` in your template.